# Highlight cells that are not in another column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare two lists (that user can select - it can be numeric values or text (10 numbers/characters long (not sure if it is important)) and highlight cells (in red) in first list that are not present in the second one. I know that it is possible to do with conditional formatting but I would like to do it with VBA.

I am receiving an "error 2015" in the immediate window in my `Debug.Print`.

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
Sub Colorcells()

Dim v1 As Range
Dim v2 As Range
Dim f As Variant

Set v1 = Application.InputBox("First list", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
Set v2 = Application.InputBox("Second list", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

lastv1 = v1.End(xlDown).Row

With Worksheets(1)
    For i = 1 To lastv1
        Debug.Print Application.Match(v1.Cells(i, 1), v2.Address)
        f = Application.Match(v1.Cells(i, 1), v2.Address, 0)
        If Not IsError(f) Then
            v1.Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

I have tried to change f data type to string/long, but then I was receiving a "type mismatch" error.
I also have tried to change the loop to (with the same error 2015 result) :

```
For i = 1 To lastv1
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(v1.Cells(i, 1), v2.Address, 0) then
        v1.Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
Next i
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably means there is no match. You are missing the final parameter on that line for an exact match.

Comment: More importantly you want to match the range, not its address, and the range must be 1d.

Comment: Thank you, v2.address returns a range as I dim'd it as a range. and v1.cells(1 ,1) returns the value contained in the first cell of v1; v1.cells(2,1) returns the value contained in the 2nd cell of v1 etc etc...

Comment: No, `v2.address` returns a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about instead of using the Match function, you use the Find one as below:

```
Sub Colorcells()
Dim v1 As Range
Dim v2 As Range
Dim found As Range

Set v1 = Application.InputBox("First list", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
Set v2 = Application.InputBox("Second list", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

For i = 1 To v1.Count
    Set found = v2.Find(What:=v1.Cells(i, 1), LookAt:=xlWhole)
    'find the value from v1 in v2
    If found Is Nothing Then
    'if not found then Color
        v1.Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: The only suggestions I would make are `Dim found As Range` and `For i = 1 To v1.count`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to adjust two lines with the following:

```
Debug.Print Application.Match(v1.Cells(i, 1), .Range(v2.Address), 0)
f = Application.Match(v1.Cells(i, 1), .Range(v2.Address), 0)
```

`.Range` will follow `With Worksheets(1)` that you specified at the beginning of this code section.

`v2.Address` is not sufficient, as it only returns the cell reference, e.g. "$B$1:$B$2". You need to wrap it in the range and also specify the sheet name.

The result:

[image]

Comment: The result ought to be the other way around, as the OP mentioned "highlight cells (in red) in first list that are not present in the second one"...

Comment: Fair point @Xabier I also noticed that and made me wonder which way around it should be, but I decided to follow the original code to show which part failed to work and explain how to adjust it. Also, I like your approach.

Comment: Hi Justyna, thank you for your answer! This code gives me an "Error 2042" for some reasons. However @Xabier code work perfectly!

Comment: @Daneel thanks for an update - it should return Error 2042 for values that do not match, and it's actual match position (like 1, 2) in case it is found. Following the example from my screenshot, Debug window prints: `1, Error 2042, Error 2042, 2, Error 2042, Error 2042`, so that only rows 1 and 4 are highlighted with red (as match is found). If you want to reverse this behaviour and highlight cells that do not match, you need to use `If IsError(f) Then` instead of `If Not IsError(f) Then`. Hope it helps!